# PHP can't copy file to Dropbox folder in Windows

Tags: php, windows, iis, dropbox

I'm using the PHP copy function to copy a file from one folder to another.  But if the folder I'm copying to is a Dropbox folder, it doesn't work.  This works fine and the file is copied into the test2 folder:

```
copy('c:/test/test.txt','c:/test2/test.txt');
```

This doesn't work and the file is not copied:

```
copy('c:/test/test.txt','c:/Dropbox/test.txt');
```

Dropbox is my root Dropbox folder.  Does anyone know of why this is happening and what I can do to fix this?  I'm using IIS and PHP on Windows Server.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check if the app pool user in iis has rights to the Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path is exactly as it appears to be. Also consider case sensitivity. That is usually a problem that throws me off. Also make sure that all permissions to the 3rd party app are validated.

Comment: The paths are correct including case sensitivity.  Which third party app are you referring to?  It's usually just Windows Explorer that moves files?

Comment: I was referring to Dropbox being a third party. Maybe the permissions from Dropbox were not set up properly to communicate with your server? I know I had this happen with NodeJs Applications I have built in the past.

Comment: No it's not Dropbox permissions.  I can easily place files into the Dropbox folder and they copy fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the issue.  It was an issue with the permissions on the Dropbox folder.  For some reason when Dropbox created the folder, it doesn't allow the folder to inherit permissions.  To fix this, I right-clicked on the Dropbox folder, selected Properties, went to the Security tab, clicked on Advanced, and then selected enable inheritance.

This allows the Dropbox folder to inherit permission from it containing folder and fixed my issue.